# Slow startup on Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install

Tags: startup

I have dual booted ubuntu 18.04 with windows 10 but i am facing slow startup on ubuntu

```
graphical.target @46.678s
└─multi-user.target @46.676s
  └─kerneloops.service @42.828s +8ms
    └─network-online.target @42.827s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @34.412s +8.414s
        └─NetworkManager.service @31.018s +3.392s
          └─dbus.service @30.460s
            └─basic.target @30.247s
              └─sockets.target @30.247s
                └─snapd.socket @30.189s +58ms
                  └─sysinit.target @30.188s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @29.988s +199ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @29.489s +477ms
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.057s +25.431s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @3.330s +725ms
                            └─systemd-journald-dev-log.socket @3.329s
                              └─system.slice @3.323s
                                └─-.slice @3.302s
```

edit 1 : systemd-analyze blame

```
    25.431s systemd-journal-flush.service
         18.934s dev-sda7.device
         13.422s systemd-udevd.service
         12.897s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
         12.810s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
         12.798s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
         12.253s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         11.904s snap-vlc-1049.mount
          9.220s snap-core-6350.mount
          8.414s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.102s bolt.service
          3.703s mnt-01D306309612D5D0.mount
          3.436s accounts-daemon.service
          3.404s udisks2.service
          3.392s NetworkManager.service
          3.231s ModemManager.service
          3.105s mnt-3AB82379B82332B5.mount
          2.964s snapd.service
          2.427s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d71546ea\x2d38ec\x2d431c\x2d80
          2.425s networkd-dispatcher.service
          2.243s networking.service
          2.192s polkit.service
          2.131s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-DE40\x2d72B8.service
lines 1-23
```

journactl --list-boots gives me this

```
11 21ac57ee5a764076bd4ca2f0d606f578 Wed 2019-07-17 09:37:48 IST—Wed 2019-07-17 
-10 3d6b343e32cf472682f7545c397f5b13 Wed 2019-07-17 10:06:34 IST—Wed 2019-07-17 
 -9 73a93657152f4bd38024a55300ece05b Wed 2019-07-17 10:20:24 IST—Wed 2019-07-17 
 -8 bb2608692ac9477f94b0301c0ebb4f42 Wed 2019-07-17 10:25:31 IST—Wed 2019-07-17 
 -7 2f956a25f9ac4c4493a0d9a248f22713 Wed 2019-07-17 11:34:54 IST—Wed 2019-07-17 
 -6 8f26b32c7a3e4d3bb2346abf16be3e07 Sat 2019-07-20 22:38:05 IST—Sat 2019-07-20 
 -5 799bf58a9df54ea3839d15dc26937384 Sun 2019-07-21 18:55:55 IST—Sun 2019-07-21 
 -4 60498b3ccaee455ba1b33abc14c45bc7 Sun 2019-07-21 13:40:40 IST—Sun 2019-07-21 
 -3 c493bf336d684eefa7f79bcbcca17e04 Sun 2019-07-21 19:51:29 IST—Sun 2019-07-21 
 -2 614ee7d9e42d40eeb632b2ff38444026 Sun 2019-07-21 15:00:38 IST—Sun 2019-07-21 
 -1 1a3ce75054b1485c9ee3b16e55e1c5b4 Sun 2019-07-21 15:10:48 IST—Sun 2019-07-21 
  0 25217cacd68d45d5bff816038ce225d8 Sun 2019-07-21 15:37:19 IST—Sun 2019-07-21
```

journalctl --disk-usage gives this

Archived and active journals take up 96.0M in the file system.

Comment: `journalctl --list-boots` and `journalctl --disk-usage` Please edit your question for output.

Answer (score 0):

You have persistent journal enabled. Make sure in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` the row `Storage=auto` is set. `sudo journalctl --rotate`  Rotate journal files. and `sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s`

After that `sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal`

Reboot. Is boot faster?

Comment: i didnt see much difference systemd-analyze blame
       
 15.487s systemd-modules-load.service   this is something new, although journal is not showing now which is good thing but still boot time is 53 seconds almost same as before

Comment: `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`  please. sometimes I hate systemd.

Comment: systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; ven
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-07-22 18:52:35 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 269 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 269 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple

Comment: I am having the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161081/systemctl-services-suddenly-timing-out I tried as `nobody` suggested to no avail.